# Taking user input to then go to a specific URL in python

Tags: python

I am in the process of making a personal assistant in python. One of the features of the personal assistant is to use Wikipedia to find information on a topic. It can already read the first 3 sentences of a Wikipedia articl, but I also want the personal assistant to open that same page in the user's default web browser. Here is a snippet of what I have tried:

```
# Function that fetches data from wikipedia

        if 'wikipedia' in statement:
            speak('Searching Wikipedia...')
            statement =statement.replace("wikipedia", "")
            webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://www.wikipedia.com/wiki/{statement}")
            results = wikipedia.summary(statement, sentences=3)
            speak("According to Wikipedia")
            speak_and_print(results)
```

But instead, it opened wikipedia.com/wiki/{statement}, which I though it might do. How can I change the ocde so that it opens a Wikipedia page, like https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the tag in the string:

If you are using a version of python3 that supports f-strings (3.6 or later, I believe), then this will work: `f"https://www.wikipedia.com/wiki/{statement}"`

Otherwise you can use this syntax: `"https://www.wikipedia.com/wiki/{}".format(statement)`

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to use f strings

```
        if 'wikipedia' in statement:
            speak('Searching Wikipedia...')
            statement =statement.replace("wikipedia", "")
            webbrowser.open_new_tab(f"https://www.wikipedia.com/wiki/{statement}")
            results = wikipedia.summary(statement, sentences=3)
            speak("According to Wikipedia")
            speak_and_print(results)
```